# How to literate each list item via ListView/GridView and checked if the checkbox is checked or not - Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Hello guys I want to check through my GridView and see if any of the checkBox is checked or not. Eventually, I want to delete the rows in my database and update my custom adapter but I'm lost on what function to use or how to approach it. I know to use some kind of while/for loop but which data type can surf and iterate each list items? I was looking around and .getChildAt(index) seems like something that would be useful but it doesn't work/appear for my custom adapter variable in my MainActivity.

Here is my Custom Adapter class for reference

```
    //variable responsible for making checkbox visible or not
    private boolean displayCheckBox;

    //constructor - it takes the context and the list of words
    WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<WordFolder> word){
        super(context, 0, word);
    }

    //sets the visibility of the checkBox
    public void setCheckBoxVisibility(boolean visible){
        this.displayCheckBox = visible;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null){
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.folder_view, parent, false);
        }

        //getting the checkBox view id
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
        checkBox.setVisibility(displayCheckBox ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        //Getting the current word
        WordFolder currentWord = getItem(position);
        //making the 3 text view to match our word_folder.xml
        TextView date_created = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.date_created);

        TextView title = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        TextView desc = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);

        //using the setText to get the text and set it in the textView
        date_created.setText(currentWord.getDateCreated());

        title.setText(currentWord.getTitle());

        desc.setText(currentWord.getTitleDesc());

        return listItemView;

    }

}
```

Comment: Does your listview keep the checked items when you scroll the list? Or when you rotate the device? Dont think so.

Comment: In getView() you should have something like `checkBox.setChecked(currendWord.isChecked());`.

Comment: @blackapps I don't have anything that keeps a track of checked items? I would love to know how to do that. Can you also further explained how the checkBox.setChecked(currentWord.isChecked()); would help or how that works?. I try doing gridView.getChildAt(i) but don't exactly know how to do that or how'd that works

Comment: Add a boolean ischecked variable to your WordFolder class. And make isChecked function in adapter class.

Comment: @blackapps I'm sorry but I'm still not sure how they will be used and tracked. like how will the WordFolder class and WordAdapter class work together and keep track of which checkbox gets tracked dynamically

Comment: You have to set an onCheckedChangeListener on the CheckBox in which you update that boolean. Once done that your checked items stay the same at scrolling.

Comment: @blackapps omg thank you so much for telling my about onCheckedChangeListener. been working on this for a while and now found a solution!